# Name for operators that commute with conjugation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that there is an operator $C$, that acts by taking the complex conjugate of every component of a vector. I have an operator $A$ that commutes with $C$, so that $AC=CA$. Is there a name for operators with this property (like "Hermitian," or "Unitary")?

Comment: "Matrices with real entries"?

Comment: How about ***real matrices***?

Comment: I have edited my question slightly in light of your comments. Yes, real matrices have this property, but I was really wondering about linear operators in general (my mistake in the title).

Comment: My notation comes from physicists who almost always write the conjugate transpose as $^\dagger$. I will go ahead and make the question even more explicit.