# Name for functions that commute with complex conjugation?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, terminology

Is there a standard term for functions $f\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with the property that $f(\overline{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$ for all $z$? Examples include analytic/meromorphic functions with only real coefficients in their Taylor/Laurent series, and intuitively, any function whose definition doesn't explicitly break the symmetry between $i$ and $-i$.

Related: [Complex Conjugate of Complex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186991/complex-conjugate-of-complex-function?rq=1), [Name for operators that commute with conjugation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027906/name-for-operators-that-commute-with-conjugation), [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle).

Comment: They are called real ( when there  is no danger of confusion with real valued functions as this property means $f$ takes real values on the real numbers in its domain which could be a subset of the plane) or conjugate invariant

Comment: @Conrad Thanks! Do you know of a textbook or similar that uses those terms?

Comment: those terms appear pretty much everywhere where complex analytic functions appear - the "real comes from polynomials as in that class, these are precisely polynomials with real coefficients